# Heroku Create Command Yielding "ENOENT" Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, command-line-interface

When attempting to call "heroku create", I get the following results:

```
Creating app... done, stack is cedar-14
      ENOENT: spawn git ENOENT
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011280/heroku-git-enoent-spawn-git-enoent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out the application was being created fine, but when I attempted to push my local repository using the command "git push heroku master" I didn't have a git remote setup.

Solved by running: git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:your-app-name-here.git

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing same problem while deploying sample node js application on heroku cloud by following the heroku tutorial. I was trying to run the "heroku create" and "git push heroku master" from Window's command prompt and it was not working due to above and other reasons.

Things started working for me when I did the same things from Gits bash session. I started git bash and ran the above commands from git bash command line.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your command prompt can't access git. I am sure you use git bash for version control.
You can avoid this if you run `heroku create` in your git bash.

Answer (score 1):

Above problem will be solve by typing following command in the command Prompt.

> > heroku login -i

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem . I think you all did  this  instructions :

```
git clone https://some reposit
cd node-js-getting-started
```

And you entered to that  catalog.

My problem  was solved when i went up in the catalog above  and tried the following command :

```
heroku create
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem will most probably happen because you are using windows as your operating system. So in windows you might be using GitBash for Git and command prompt for Heroku.
Just try checking out the git version from command line in your directory, most probably the output will be 'git' not recognized.
 
So now if you use Gitbash for git commands, this is where the problem lies because GitBash does not recognize Heroku.
When you enter the command Heroku create in Command line it creates the app but instead of returning a link of your project, it yields an error message like this - `'ENOENT: spawn git ENOENT',`
 
If you try to enter Heroku commands in GitBash they'll also not be recognized.
**Hence the only solution to this is try making the command line recognize Git by re-installing Git and choosing `Command Line` as its terminal instead of Bash** .This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if your have cloned some project and trying to upload it, at this time it can show this type error. so just delete the original git repo (ex .git folder) and try again  command

> heroku create your_app_name

and than create new git repo