# Heroku + git = ENOENT: spawn git ENOENT

Tags: linux, git, heroku

I'm new to Ubuntu 17.04.
So I'm having some trouble with git and Heroku.

When I run `$ heroku create` or trying to clone an exciting repository/app created on Windows `heroku git:clone -a appname` I get the error. `ENOENT: spawn git ENOENT`.

I've done some searching it seems to be that either git isn't installed or the PATH is wrong or not set properly. But I have installed git `$ sudo apt-get install git`

`$ git --version
git version 2.11.0`

`$ git --exec-path
/usr/lib/git-core`

And I installed Heroku-CLI using snap as their documentation states. `$ sudo snap install heroku`

`$ which heroku
/snap/bin/heroku`

`$ heroku --version
heroku-cli/6.12.0 (linux-x64) node-v7.10.0`

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the Heroku-CLI version and installed using snap.

Comment: removing the snap version and using the one from the APT repos solved this and other problems for me as well!