# Every command heroku fails with 'ENOENT': spawn tasklist ENOENT

Tags: heroku-cli

I am aware [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011280/heroku-git-enoent-spawn-git-enoent) exists already but he had a different issue as he answered himself. I am running on windows 32 bit and trying to run heroku. It stopped somehow after I restart the terminal one time. Now literally anything I enter using the heroku cli, I get this error:

```
'ENOENT': spawn tasklist ENOENT
```

I tried running `heroku version` but still the same. In my path I have linked it to `C:\. . .\Heroku\bin`. It worked but even after reinstalling it does not work.

P.S. Does this have anything to do with my node installation? I have node installed too. Is it clashing?

Comment: I'm supposed to literally deploy today but I am not able to... Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, while I was not operating as Administrator. When running heroku commands as admin in shell, it started working. I found this discussion to be helpful: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras/issues/129.

Hope that helps.
Cheers

Comment: Alright thanks! It turns out though I had to go through a re-installation and manually remove some folders which were causing the problem. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you need to locate tasklist.exe on your PC.

Typically, it is found in Windows/system32/

If it is there, put the basepath to it in PATH Environmental variable.

Then open new cmd.exe as Administrator.

Now, you should NOT see the `'ENOENT': spawn tasklist ENOENT` error message.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issues but i resolved mine by running cmd as adminstrator. and login back into heroku by using these command 
`heroku auth:login`
and wala! you can bounce back to your project.

i recommend looking at these
[helpful link](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras/issues/129)